# How to sum and recognize and return case '0' , and '-' in

Tags: javascript, if-statement, sum, return

```js
function sum2(num) {
  let sum ;
  let str = String(num)
  for(let i = 0 ; i < str.length; i++){
  if(i === 0) {
    sum = parseInt(str[i]);
    
  } else {
    sum = sum + parseInt(str[i])
  }
  }
    return sum;
}
debugger;
let output = sum2(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14 = 1 + 1 + 4 + 8

output = sum2(-316);
console.log(output); // --> 4 = -3 + 1 + 6
```

i need to case num is -316, and num is 0
but it will be return 'NaN'..

what should i do..?

Comment: Well, a hint is that `String(-316)` is `"-316"`, where index 0 is `"-"`, 1 is `"3"`, 2 is `"1"`, and 3 is `"6"`. You'll want to check if the first character is `"-"`, and if it is, then do something different for the first two iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take care of the '-' (minus)

```js
function sum2(num) {
  let sum = 0;
  const str = String(num)
  let multipler = 1;
  for (let i = 0 ; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0 && str[i] === "-") {
      multipler = -1;
    } else {
      sum += multipler * parseInt(str[i], 10);
      multipler = 1;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sum2(1148)); // --> 14 = 1 + 1 + 4 + 8
console.log(sum2(-316)); // --> 4 = -3 + 1 + 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but you also have to add a condition to check for the minus sign.

```
function sum2(num) {
   let sum = 0;
   let str = String(num)
   for(let i = 0 ; i < str.length; i++){
      if(i === 0) {
        if(str[i] == '-'){
           sum = sum - parseInt(str[i+1]);
           i = i+1;
          }else{
           sum = parseInt(str[i]);
           }

       }else {
           sum = sum + parseInt(str[i])
        }
    }
     return sum;
}
debugger;
let output = sum2(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14 = 1 + 1 + 4 + 8

output = sum2(-316);
console.log(output); // --> 4 = -3 + 1 + 6
```